# To decouple or not to decouple? That could be the question

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I read some very interesting discussions about decoupling microservices on this forum. One of the approaches is to ensure each service holds (parts of) the data of another context to allow it to operate without having a dependency on other services (e.g. REST call to other services).

Where does one draw the line while "duplicating" data among different services?

Assume you have two different services. One services manages product data while another service manages health data. At a certain point in time, you want to introduce AI to the project and decide to build a dedicated service to provide data for model training purposes. This data provider service could decide to store parts of the product data and parts of the health data to do its task. This inevitably results in huge amounts of data being duplicated consuming a lot of storage resources (10000s of products, 1000s of users), but still decoupled. Or, the data provider could store no data at all and retrieve all required data by calling other services resulting in tight coupling.

Under such circumstances, is this still considered a good idea? I know there is no rule of thumb and everything depends on what the solution needs. I just have the feeling I am overlooking something or misinterpreting the idea behind the "duplication of (parts of) the data".

Comment: What's the concern? The cost in terms of computation resources? The duplicated data itself? The complexity?

Comment: It is not as much about how to duplicate the data or the availability of the required computation resources. The question is more about if this is an acceptable design approach or would it be better under such conditions to "violate" best practises/recommendations?

Comment: You are missing the main goal of building up a system. Solving a "problem". Or make money or both at the same time. Principles are only guiding rules in case you need a sort of guidance at the moment of making decisions. Think of them like a compass. They are not universal laws written in stone. You can ignore'em until you can't. So. is it a good idea? yes and no. They can be both good or bad... until proven the opposite. That's why the question is getting flagged. The theory is useless without a real-world use case. Meanwhile, the answer is always the same *it depends*.

Comment: `I just have the feeling I am overlooking something or misinterpreting the idea behind the "duplication of (parts of) the data` or, maybe, you are approaching principles from a dogmatic point of view. Real-world solutions are never all white or black. They are somewhere within a grey area where nothing is as good as we wish but definitively it could be worse. So yes, you are overlooking this a bit.

Comment: @Laiv +1 on the dogma. The question in well-intentioned but unfortunately steeped in the expectation of dogma.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone answering this question. Since all of them are very helpful to me, I would like to mark each of them as answer. Unfortunately, this cannot be done. Sharing your insights is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to data warehousing, business analytics or in this case AI/ML analytics (which is a comparable case), the usual strategy is to build snapshots from the production data and store them in a dedicated database or storage system. These snapshots are often retrieved by some ETL process, they are aggregated and optimized for analytical purposes, and it is typically a good idea to have them completely decoupled (software and hardware) from the "life" processes, since the processes that work on them will have very different requirements than the online processes on the production data. And yes, those snapshots may require a lot of extra storage space.

This kind of data typically *must* be copies of the original data, since one needs different version of it over time to evaluate them in a sensible manner. However, this does not cause any issues with data duplication, since the data is "frozen" and will not get mixed up with the online live data used for online transaction processing. Note this has *nothing* to do with micro services, data ware house architectures are well known for at least 20 years, before even the term "micro service" was invented.

A different question is how to handle overlapping data from two online services ("micro" or not). Here, it usually is a judgement call how much duplication one will allow in such a system, or where the data is maintained (in service A, B, or some third service C). In general, however, it is a praxis-proven strategy to make only *one* service responsible for maintaining a certain piece of data, and give all other services just read-only access to the same piece. This is in line with data warehouse or analytics approach above - there, the online systems are the only ones where the data is created and maintained, whilst the snapshots are just "read-only" copies, maybe in an aggregated form.

Comment: I see what you mean. I agree it is indeed a better approach to handle all AI related aspects completely separated from the rest of the solution.

Comment: It's not better. It's only convenient. There could be situations where living data is required. Say real-time analytics within a well-defined time frame. It's contextual, as any other solution-vs-problem. In this particular case, decoupling is almost mandatory since you can not afford the AI to tax business systems while training. Unless you have unlimited resources to scale out/off both systems (AI and Business) or you can attach de AI system to the business input streams.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of data you should copy: product prices, when creating an order.

Simply put, if I sell thingamajigs for $100 today and you buy one, I would create an order and refer to the product you bought. But tomorrow, I might start selling the thingamajigs for $150.
If your order only contained a reference to the product and an implicit expectation that I could find the price you paid by looking at the product in the order, I would not be able to see that you bought it for $100 instead of $150. If you needed a refund, that's a dangerous way for me to lose money because I'd give you back more than you gave me. If you need me to reprint your order confirmation, I would also need to be able to list the actual price you paid me.

We should instead store the product price *at the time* in the order itself, because it is a **snapshot** of the price and it should not change even when the product's price does change in the future.

Snapshots are a form of functional duplication. They are made in order to ensure the application works as it should (e.g. by being able to refund customers correctly, or generate correct invoices after an order has been made).

Caches are arguably a subset of snapshots, in the sense that I suggest you don't cache data *unless* you are doing so to meet a functional standard that you otherwise would not be able to meet, e.g. application performance.

> Or, the data provider could store no data at all and retrieve all required data by calling other services resulting in tight coupling.

That's not what tight coupling is. Tight coupling refers to the coherence of the code, not the amount of interactions during runtime.

Regardless, there is a runtime consideration here. Are you able to tolerate the impact to performance whenever someone feels like running the AI/ML process? Is it really okay for this to detract from the production data performance?
Secondly, this is also going to impact the speed at which the AI/ML process can process the data. Is it really okay for the process to now have to wait for IO operations to get access to a rather large bulk set of data?
Thirdly, is there a cost to your bandwidth/infrastructure in order to provide for all of these network calls?

If you see no concerns in what I just mentioned, then there's no point to caching this data. If you do, that means that *not caching* the data would cause you to miss an application requirement (expected performance, required infrastructure cost, ...), which means the caching has a purpose.

You already hit the nail on the head when you said:

> I know there is no rule of thumb and **everything depends on what the solution needs**.

The short answer, which is only approximately correct, is that you generally want to avoid duplication/caching unless you can reasonably justify doing so.

Comment: So tight coupling is not related to dependencies between multiple services to allow them to complete their task(s)? That is something I misunderstood then. As far as I understood, data duplication (limited to what is necessary) is one way to prevent one service from being unable to complete a task caused by the unavailability of other services.

Comment: @KDW. Tight coupling isn't measured by the # of calls you make. Coupling is a metric of abstraction. One can often be correlated to the other but they're not the same thing.

Comment: @KDW: Maybe a better way to put it: I can write two tightly coupled components who share no data between them, and I can write two loosely coupled components who transfer exabytes of data between them. Coupling is better measured by a consequential need for change, i.e. the degree to which I am able to make changes to one component without needing to make changes to the other. It is inevitable that changing the structure of the interface between them will obviously impact both of them, but you can loosely couple them to prevent needing to change said interface (e.g. mapping).

Answer (score 2):

As you suspect, it is best to minimize duplication as much as possible to avoid wasting resources and keep the services decoupled. However, there may be cases where it is necessary to duplicate *some* data to allow a service to operate independently.

In the situation you described, it may be necessary for the data provider service to store some data to provide data for model training. However, it is essential to carefully consider how much data is needed and only to duplicate the minimum amount necessary.

One approach to avoid duplication while still allowing the data provider service to operate independently is using a shared cache or shared database that all services can access. This way, the data provider service can store the necessary data in the shared cache or database and retrieve it as needed without having to duplicate the data across multiple services. This, of course, introduces some co-dependencies and coupling, but it might be a viable solution in your case.

Another possible approach is to use an event-driven architecture, where each service publishes events when data is updated. Other services can subscribe to these events to receive updates in real time. This way, the data provider service can subscribe to events from the different services and receive updates potentially without duplicating any data if it only needs to keep an overall state and not all data.

Ultimately, the best approach will depend on the specific needs of the solution and the trade-offs between decoupling, duplication, and performance.

For more information, it's worth taking a look at the more general problem of [OLTP vs. OLAP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-olap-and-oltp-in-dbms/).